# Use multiple css classnames in react js

Tags: css, reactjs

i would like to resize my button and i understand i will need to use classname for this.

**Here's my component**

```
              <Tour
                steps={steps}
                isOpen={this.state.isTourOpen}
                onRequestClose={this.closeTour}
                rounded={5}
                className="reactour_helper_large"
              />
```

**Here's my CSS code**

```
.reactour_helper_large{ 
    max-width: 80% 
}
.reactour_close{ 
    width: 15px;
}
```

**Here's the HTML code**

I am able to resize my tab using reactour_helper_large. However when i put something like `className="reactour_helper_large reactour_close"`, the css for reactour_close gets applied on the main tab as well. How do i edit it such that it only applies for the button class highlighted below? Thank you.

[image]

Comment: combine css statements like `button.class-name`, then the class-name will only apply the the tag `button` with the class of `class-name`. Assuming I understood your question correctly.

Comment: Hmm something like `className="reactour_helper_large button.reactour_close"`?

Comment: no... in <button className="reactour_helper_large reactour_close">Click Me</button> then in your css you have: `button.reactour_close{
    width: 15px;
}`
Note that this will only apply the rule width: `15px` to the class `reactour_close` when it is applied to a `button tag`. Of course you would use whatever tag/class you need to make it only apply where you needed it to apply.

Comment: Tried this but still not working. Maybe i missed something out. Here's the sandbox, are you able to see the updated classname? - https://codesandbox.io/s/gracious-breeze-pxhyvr?file=/src/index.tsx

Comment: Alright I'm not sure I understand what you mean.... Is it the fact that you should be using `.reactour__close` notice the double underscore "_"... Please see https://codesandbox.io/s/musing-moser-zf4ikj?file=/src/styles.css for example.

Comment: Oh i missed out this `.reactour_helper_large` in the CSS. So it didn't work. After looking through ur code it works fine now. Thank you!